# Type Inferance using Fetch with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, react-typescript, react-query

I wrote a Fetch wrapper to fetch my API using Typescript. I would like, when I'm getting back my data from my API, getting from the "any" type to my eg: "user" type.

I paste you a link for my codesandebox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-error-rkmv1

When I console.log in the onSuccess callback (or even in the fetch directly), even if the Typescript compiler doesn't complain, and I can use my fetched data as a "User", if I log this User, it is not really a User. It is a object that I can use "as" a User, but not a "User".

I could leave it like that because in the end, it works and my result is typical, but I'm afraid that it poses other problems that I didn't imagine.

Thanks !

Comment: I had the same OCD issue once, I found a useful typescript generic called ```Partial```. It basically takes your interface and makes it a "partial" version, so in your casting use ```data as Partial<T>```...Try it I guess

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it does not work, I make my "post" function return Promise<Partial<T>> and my fetch(..).then(data => data as Partial<T> but that change nothing :|

Comment: It is not really meant to change anything except for your tpyings, it accommodates the scenario you're in more flexibly by saying that the returned data of your request may be a Partial version of the return you have defined...https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Try adding the return definition to your functions like this ```function post<T>(input: Request | string, body: object, init?): Promise<Partial<T>> { ... }```

Comment: Yeah, that what I did, but at the end, my object is still the one from the API (any) and not the one I defined (User or UserWithtoken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using and interface. On runtime typescript interfaces, or any custom type, does not exist, are just a plain object, a signature for typescript. Only classes are "visible" in actual JavaScript code, but you should instantiate the class using `new` operator.

As you said, "it poses other problems that I didn't imagine". The solution is to create a class in addition to the interface, so you can interact with it.

```typescript
export interface IUserData {
  // id: number; // ID should not be part of the data
  name: string;
  firstName: string;
  email: string;
  password?: string;
}

export class User {
  public readonly attributes: IUserData;

  constructor(data: Partial<IUserData>, public readonly id?: number) {
    // validate and initialize default values of attributes

    this.attributes = { /* all keys with default values*/ };
  }
}
```

Then, you can use the interface as signature of the response and create a new instance with `const model = new User(response.data, response.id)`, for example. That way you can add "features" to the class to share between instances. `model.attributes` has the raw attributes ready to be used. You can create getters/setters for direct access to attributes, etc.

> [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) is an utility type of typescript core to tell an object has attributes of T, but optional. This is useful if you are working with PATCH for only `email`, for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! I tried your solution, it is working but I'm not sure : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-error-forked-c5k2y?file=/src/api/useAuth.tsx I forked my sandbox. I I need to create "new User()" at each onSuccess callback, I don't know where is it useful, because I lost the "automatic map", no? Or perhaps I didn't understand what you mean. But If possible, I just want the "User" object in the onSuccess (or userWithtoken in the case of signin)

Comment: I think your solution is better than mine, but.. I don't know if I implemented it the right way, and so, I still had to create new instance of User at each onSuccess, which is... Odd for something that should be simple ? Or I don't know, what is the better solution instead. And, as my API use HATEOS, I need something flexible. eg: my user entity has a link to a project entity whith ID. What if I want to return the userEntity with the idProjectEntity ?

Comment: @Deewens You create the instance and map it in your post() function, when you call `fetch().then()`.  Instead of returning  `data as T` you can map it to instance and return it (I meant, move a portion of your code from useAuth.tsx to fetchWrapper.ts).

Comment: Btw, remember that you are wrapping the raw data in the class constructor. So, make sure you initialize all attributes it needs.

Comment: BTW, in your code you are not exporting the User class (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-error-forked-c5k2y?file=/src/types/index.d.ts) as you are importing on useAuth.tsx line 2

Comment: Ok, so, thanks for your answer, this is a good solution, I did not implemented it yet, but I will update my codebase later. I am just wondering, why ID should not be part of the data?

Comment: @Deewens Because is not something you need to change. It's just a metadata to identify the object in the database. You only want to change attributes in your `data` object.

Answer (score 0):

so i noticed that if you want your IDE to reflect the return of your function you need to explicitly define the return of your function, let us take the get function that you had provided in your link...

```
function get<T>(input: Request | string, init?): Promise<Partial<T>> { // so the return is defined here
  const token = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

  const requestInit = {
    method: "GET",
    ...init
  };

  if (token) {
    requestInit.headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      ...requestInit.headers
    };
  }

  return fetch(apiUrl + input, requestInit)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => data as T);
}
```

Give it a shot...thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-error-forked-bxtqb?file=/src/api/useAuth.tsx  but, there is no change, instead that I received an object with property "string | undefined"